# Go and UTF-8 encoding - Is conversion automatic?

Tags: unicode, encoding, go, utf-8, character-encoding

I am making http requests using Go.

```
request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
```

This request, if successful, returns a response.

```
response, err := client.Do(request)
```

After receiving a response, I want to save the content.

```
content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
ioutil.WriteFile(destination, content, 0644)
```

I looked at the Headers of the responses.

```
response.Header.Get("Content-Type")
```

I saw the majority are already UTF-8 encoded, which is good. But there are some that have different encodings. I know Go has built in unicode support. Does that mean that if I write, for example, the content of a big-5 encoded page, it will be automatically converted to utf-8? Or do I need to manually decode using the big-5 encoding and re-encode using utf-8?

Basically, I want to ensure that everything that gets written is utf-8 encoded. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate of [Go encoding transform issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651410/go-encoding-transform-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `ioutil.ReadAll` reads will be written with `ioutil.WriteFile` without any conversions whatsoever.

If you want to force UTF-8 encoded you will have to do the de-/encoding yourself, e.g. with the help of `golang.org/x/text/encoding{,/charmap}` and/or the `unicode/utf{8,16}` packages.

Be prepared for all sorts of ugliness and a lot of pain.

Comment: "Be prepared for all sorts of ugliness and a lot of pain."  Yeah ... I was hoping to avoid that with Go. I had to deal with that in Python ... Never again. Anyways, thanks for the answer.

Comment: As mat sated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651410/go-encoding-transform-issue some pain might be relieved by golang.org/x/net/html/charset .